# Docusign integration with anchor tags

Tags: docusignapi

I have a working Docusign integration, which has been in place for some time by passing co-ordinates to the Docusign API.

However, I would like to use anchor tags instead which is supposed to be supported - yet every time I change it, I get an error from Docusign stating:

```
{
  "errorCode": "NO_DOCUMENT_RECEIVED",
  "message": "The document element did not contain the encoded document, or there is a problem with the encoding. Bytes for document corresponding to documentId 1 not found in request. 'documentId=<x>' possibly missing from Content-Disposition header."
}
```

I have seen other posts with this error, but they are always caused by the way the body of the request is built.  However, I am changing nothing in the rest of the request - I am simply changing from using co-ordinates to anchor tags.

Working request:

```
{"status":"sent","emailBlurb":"<EMAIL BODY GOES HERE>","emailSubject":"subject","documents":[{"name":"DocumentNameCanBeCustomised","documentId":1,"order":null}],"recipients":{"signers":[{"email":"User@example.com","name":"David","recipientId":1,"tabs":{"signHereTabs":[{"documentId":1,"xPosition":100,"yPosition":100,"pageNumber":1}],"approveTabs":[]},"routingOrder":null}]}}
```

Failing request:

```
{"status":"sent","emailBlurb":"<EMAIL BODY GOES HERE>","emailSubject":"subject","documents":[{"name":"DocumentNameCanBeCustomised","documentId":1,"order":null}],"recipients":{"signers":[{"email":"user@example.com","name":"David","recipientId":1,"tabs":{"signHereTabs":[{"documentId":1,"anchorString":"PO box 459","anchorXOffset":"0","anchorYOffset":"0","anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent":"false","anchorUnits":"inches"}],"approveTabs":[]},"routingOrder":null}]}}
```

Any advise would be appreciated - the full request is below and is the same for both requests other than the JSON.

---

```
POST https://demo.docusign.net:7802/restapi/v2/accounts/688891/envelopes
Content-Length: 67039
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=BOUNDARY
Accept: application/json
Expect: 100-continue
Host: demo.docusign.net
X-DocuSign-Authentication: {"Username":"X979d5e3-778a-4a2b-b4d5-a91025d5f7ba","Password":"[omitted]","IntegratorKey":"[omitted]"}
X-Forwarded-For: 81.133.16.170



--BOUNDARY
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Disposition: form-data

{"status":"sent","emailBlurb":"blurb","emailSubject":"subject","documents":[{"name":"DocumentNameCanBeCustomised","documentId":1,"order":null}],"recipients":{"signers":[{"email":"David@example.com","name":"David","recipientId":1,"tabs":{"signHereTabs":[{"anchorString":"userid below this","anchorXOffset":"0","anchorYOffset":"0","anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent":"false","anchorUnits":"inches"}],"approveTabs":[]},"routingOrder":null}]}}

--BOUNDARY
Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Disposition: file; filename="Contract.pdf"; documentId=1
%PDF-1.5
%{{BYTES REMOVED}}
--BOUNDARY--


400 BadRequest
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8

{  "errorCode": "NO_DOCUMENT_RECEIVED",
  "message": "The document element did not contain the encoded document, or there is a problem with the encoding. Bytes for document corresponding to documentId 1 not found in request. 'documentId=<x>' possibly missing from Content-Disposition header."}
```

Thanks,
David

Comment: The "working request" JSON you posted is not valid, please post correctly formatted JSON for starters.

Comment: Assuming that's not the issue, I see you are trying to anchor to the text `"PO box 459"`, is that correct?  If that specific text is not anywhere in the document you'll get an error.

Comment: It means that the request is missing the document bytes altogether OR there is an issue w/the definition of how you are defining the document. Try to include more of the request and you can use a snippet of the document bytes to make the post shorter.

Comment: Thanks Ergin - I have fixed the JSON (a double quote was accidently removed when removing the original email subject).  The text is correct and does exist in the doc - that was just one example of some text in the document.

Comment: Thanks @LuisScott - I have added the full request for completeness as you suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend that you add a specific string to the document for use as an anchor. Eg "<<sig1>>" (And then change its text color to white so you won't see it in the doc.)

I've had problems with using existing text as an anchor, especially text with spaces in it.

Another tip: try using the [web browser DocuSign app](http://docusign.net) to create an envelope, with the same document, with a Signing Field that uses the anchor text.

For more information, see the [recipe](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/recipes/autoplace).

Comment: I originally tried using a GUID - and that failed so I changed it to a different piece of text as part of troubleshooting.  Thanks for the tip though - will certainly try that later and will report back.

Comment: Perfect - you were right on the text with spaces in it.  The scenarios I tried either had spaces, or had guids with an unusual separator (from an external system) and both caused the API to send back the unrelated error above.  Using some text without any separator seems to have solved the issue.  Thanks for the tip!